# tcolorbox, lstlisting has hanging indent by default even for TeX source?

Tags: tcolorbox, lstlisting

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\tcbset{
  codefullblock/.style={
    listing only,
    listing options={
      language=TeX, style=tcblatex, texcsstyle=*\color{blue}\bfseries
    }}
}

\newtcblisting{mycodeblock}{
  codefullblock
}

\begin{document}

Try this MWE:

\begin{mycodeblock}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\TeX is a control word.

Since a control word is ended by any non-letter, the space at the end of the control word for \textbackslash TeX is not typeset as a space. Instead, it is absorbed to indicate the end of that control word.

You'll notice that the backslash control word is similarly ended by a space, and that space is not typeset as a space.

The right way to type the above sentence would be:

\TeX\ is a control word.
\end{document}
\end{mycodeblock}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes and no, in code there are no paragraphs and normally text is printed as written line by line, but your lines are too long, so they are wrapped. This line wrapping is shown by indentation to avoid confusion with a real new line. You could add `breakindent=0pt,` to the listings options.

Comment: @moewe Oh yes. Forgot that. Want me to mark your reply as the answer? I would like to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally listings reads and prints the input verbatim line by line. In your example the lines are very long and so they are broken to fit onto the page. To mark the continuation of a broken line, the subsequent line is indented by 20pt (that's the default value of `listings`, I didn't check if `tcolorbox` changes it). This indentation can be turned off with `breakindent=0pt,`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\tcbset{
  codefullblock/.style={
    listing only,
    listing options={
      language=TeX, style=tcblatex, texcsstyle=*\color{blue}\bfseries,
      breakindent=0pt,
    }}
}

\newtcblisting{mycodeblock}{
  codefullblock
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mycodeblock}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc convallis, libero vel pellentesque dignissim, mi nulla lacinia neque, sit amet dapibus sem nibh non libero. Vestibulum consectetur neque eu risus aliquet, sed tincidunt felis hendrerit. Morbi et diam sed dolor posuere aliquet id quis neque. Aenean in ipsum sollicitudin, ultricies tortor non, varius nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse viverra tortor ultrices consequat tempor. Phasellus interdum mi vitae mauris dapibus, in sodales tortor tincidunt. Pellentesque sagittis eu lectus cursus rhoncus. Vivamus feugiat sit amet nisi eu rutrum. Donec mollis metus at varius ultrices. Suspendisse tempor metus a erat viverra scelerisque. Vivamus convallis, mi et pulvinar porttitor, mi orci tempor est, a eleifend velit mi at felis.

Mauris eu risus id erat iaculis sagittis. Cras auctor finibus dolor. Aliquam tincidunt ligula eu purus tristique sollicitudin. Aliquam tempor mauris viverra lorem porttitor, nec maximus nisl venenatis. Proin et mattis sapien. Vivamus auctor, nunc cursus tempus semper, felis eros sodales nisl, vitae scelerisque nibh urna quis nulla. Vestibulum congue nibh pulvinar ex suscipit fermentum. Fusce non eros lectus.
\end{mycodeblock}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Genius. That was quick. I'm glad I'm alive in these times with people like you.